# obfuscate not working in nodejs project

Tags: node.js

I am trying to search obfuscate module for nodejs app. My file structure is as follows:

```
index.js
assets
  -> file1.js
  -> file2.js
controller
  -> file1.js
  -> file2.js
```

Comment: I have cleaned up the format to make the folder structure more apparent.

Answer (score 0):

Actually minification would do something 'similar' to obfuscation. But keep in mind the main purpose of minification is to make the file size smaller by trimming extra chars, which contributes to the file being downloaded faster. It can be un-minified when received on the browser.

Look up `combine and minify js`. You'll find a bunch of tools to accomplish this.